# Processing array of hashrefs correctly

Tags: perl

I have an list of maps in my code.

```
my @codeList;
push (@codeList, \%map1, \%map2, \%map3);
```

when I am trying to access it via looping over List index it is not giving me proper map. 
what am I missing.

```
my $Count = @codeList;
for (my $index =0; $index < $Count; $index++)
{
    my %map = $codeList[$index];                
}
```

Comment: Show us the code please. How do you looping over the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
my %map = $dbColsList[$dbCount];
```

you have to use reference as `@codeList` was populated with them => `\%map1`

```
my $map = $dbColsList[$dbCount];
```

and later use it like `$map->{key}` as this is [`array of hashes`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#ARRAYS-OF-HASHES) or hashref structure.

Check [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) for details.

Alternatively you can dereference hashref and do a shallow copy (changes to `%map` keys/values won't reflect on `\%map1`, etc.)

```
my %map = %{ $dbColsList[$dbCount] };
```

Comment: Alternative you can dereference on the loop `my %map = %{$codeList[$index]};` and use %map normally

Comment: @salparadise tnx for comment.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works fine. i think its your loop ( which you did'nt show us). You can loop through this by dereferencing the hashref (`%{ $hashref }`):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my %map1 = (test1 => 'ab');
my %map2 = (test2 => 'ab');
my %map3 = (test2 => 'ab');

my @codeList;
push (@codeList, \%map1, \%map2, \%map3);

for my $hashref (@codeList) {
  for my $key (keys %{$hashref}) {
    say $key . q{ } . $hashref->{$key};
  }
}
```

EDIT Output:

```
test1 ab
test2 ab
test2 ab
```